# iScroll4 - all Next / Prev buttons controlling bottom Carousel - JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, iscroll4

I've created a JSFiddle for my problem, but for some bizarre reason, even tho I've precisely placed working online example into this JSFiddle [jsfiddle.net/r9VL2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/r9VL2/1/) - it's not working?

Can anyone get it working like my online example ['Carousel within Simple Vertical Scrolller'](http://www.motocomdigital.co.uk/development/cubiq/examples/simple/), that would be good for starters :)

But my actual problem as you can see here ['Carousel within Simple Vertical Scrolller'](http://www.motocomdigital.co.uk/development/cubiq/examples/simple/) is that the **Prev** and **Next** buttons all control the last carousel.

Can anyone help me slim down the javascript and get it so the **Prev** and **Next** Buttons work for there parent carousel, instead of just all controlling the last carousel.

Any pro help would be awesome thanks.

Josh

Scan code below to test on your device.

[image: QR CODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable multiple times - thats not going to work - if you create a separate variable for each section / scroll then it works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/r9VL2/2/

Im sure there are better ways to create the variable / keep track of what scroll should be used when

Comment: Thanks dude, maybe this... var scroll, scroll1, scroll2, scroll3;

Comment: Just curious, was this the only thing you had to do to the JSfiddle to work? Is to change the varibles through out the script and html? Thanks